# CGI scripts and Python - .format() IndexError

Tags: python, cgi

```
print("<table>")
for line in range(1,11):
    for table in range(1,11):
    print("<tr>{0}".format(line))
    print("</tr>")
    product = line*table
    print("<td>{1}".format(product))
    print("</td>")
    print()
print("</table>")
```

This program just makes a simple multiplication table. I am trying to write a CGI script and format Python's outputs into an HTML table. The code above is what I have currently. I've tried many different ways in trying to get this table to display correctly. No matter what, the second .format() gives me that index error. I feel a little silly considering how easy the program before I turn it into a CGI script:

```
for line in range(1,11):
    for table in range(1,11):
        print(line*table,"\t",end='')
    print()
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great! I know this is a fairly simple fix that I'm just not understanding.

Comment: Yes second is wrong:  `print("<td>{1}".format(product))` gives error it should be `print("<td>{0}".format(product))`   not `{1}` but `{0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you write only into a string with a single line with only one placeholder the string doesn't find the index, therefore will complain.
You can replace

```
print("<td>{1}".format(product))
print("<td>{0}".format(product))
```

If you want to combine it you can do something like

```
"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>".format(1,2)
'<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>'
```